# How can I use interceptor in neo4j-graphql-js endpoint with nestjs framework?

Tags: javascript, neo4j, graphql, interceptor, nestjs

I am using the neo4j-graphql-js library to translate graphql queries to cypher and I need to implement an interceptor to verify that what is returning belongs to the user who is asking for it. For this I need to implement the interceptor but the problem I have is that I have no resolvers since it generates the liberia. How can I make it go through the interceptor? If the interceptor cannot be used, is there a way to implement a middleware in the response?

I'm using nestjs framework. And I use a neo4j database.

Thank you.

Module:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRootAsync({
      useClass: GraphqlConfigService,
    }),
  ],
  providers: [neo4jProvider],
})

export class GraphqlModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(GraphQLAuthMiddleware,GraphQLRoleMiddleware)
      .forRoutes('graphql');
  }

}
```

```
@Injectable()
export class GraphqlConfigService implements GqlOptionsFactory {
  async createGqlOptions(): Promise<GqlModuleOptions> {
   const schema = buildSchema();

    return {
      playground: true,
      schema: schema,
      path: '/graphql/queries',
      context: {
        driver: neo4j.driver(
          'bolt://neo4j_db:7687',
          neo4j.auth.basic('neo4j', 'root')
        )
      }

    };
  }
}

function buildSchema(): GraphQLSchema {
  return makeAugmentedSchema({
    typeDefs,
    config: {
      query: true,
      mutation: true
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind your interceptor globally either by using the `app.useGlobalInterceptors(MyCustomInterceptor)` method in your `main.ts` or in *any* module you can add the interceptor in your providers array

```
@Module({
  imports: [/* your imports*/],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
      useClass: MyCustomInterceptor
    },
    /* the rest of your providers*/
  ],
})
export class GraphqlModule {}
```

`APP_INTERCEPTOR` is imported from `@nestjs/core`. Keep in mind, this does bind the interceptor globally. All requests to your server will go through this interceptor.